# Plot p density vs Probability of heads in R

Tags: r, plot, probability

I signed up late for a class so I wasn't assigned a group for my first homework assignment yet so I'm turning here for help.

Given a fair coin with 1000 tosses, what's the probability that you will get Heads 750 times or more, when the probability varies from .5 to .95 in intervals of .01. Display your results on a plot with Pr(Heads) on Y and the Variable probability on Y.

What I have so far:

```
n <- 1000 #number of tosses
p <- seq(0.5, 0.95, 0.01) #probability of heads for each toss
X <- rbinom(n, 750 ,p) #random binomial distribution which will return number of heads
Pr.X <- X/n #probability is number greater than or equal to 750 of heads over total tosses
plot(p, dbinom(n, Pr.X, p)) # I'm not too sure on dbinom but a quick google search said that's how we plot binomial distributions
```

I keep getting an error stating that x and the y lengths differ. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Seems like a fair question. You're almost there. Insetad of `rbinom` (draw random binomial) use `dbinom` (probability of drawing random binom) and make sure to set `x = 750` and `n = 1000`. This will plot the pdf of the binomial distribution. You can read about the functions in `help(rbinom)`.

Comment: TYVM! So if I use dbinom, thats already taking the probability so would the step of X/n be unnecessary? I would just plot(p,X)?

Comment: You've got it exactly right. Add `type = "l"` to your plot function for good measures. 

Comment: But don't use `dbinom`:  it gives the probability of exactly 750 successes.  You want 750 or more, so use `pbinom(..., lower.tail = FALSE)`.

Comment: Interesting, can you elaborate more on what lower.tail = false would do?